# MariaDB having syntax in a new MariaDB install

Tags: sql, mariadb, pymysql

I have developed some Python scripts that inserts data into a MariaDB database using PyMySQL library.

The scripts was working well until yesterday. Yesterday the HDD of the server died. I just installed 3 disks (1 for boot and SWAP, the other two are in a raid 1 with EXT4 and / mounting point). When the main packages are ready, I found the scripts aren't working well due to the next query

```
INSERT
INTO
    devices(
        source_id,
        serialnumber,
        NAME,
        location_desc
    )
SELECT
    2,
    '5996B',
    'Barbate',
    'CADIZ'
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        devices
    WHERE
        serialnumber = '5996B'
)
```

This query insert a device into devices table if the device not exists. The scripts work well in my local MariaDB server, but not in the production one, giving the next error:

```
Error

SQL query: Documentation

INSERT
INTO
    devices(
        source_id,
        serialnumber,
        NAME,
        location_desc
    )
SELECT
    2,
    '5996B',
    'Barbate',
    'CADIZ'
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        devices
    WHERE
        serialnumber = '5996B'
)

MariaDB said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        devices
    W' at line 14
```

I think that is a compatibility issue with a newer version of MariaDB. How can I fix it without rewriting my Python scripts?

EDIT:

Results for:
`SELECT VERSION();`

Response in local server (where the SQL statement works):
`10.4.6-MariaDB`

Response in production server (where the SQL statement doesn't work):
`10.3.17-MariaDB-0+deb10u1`

Comment: Where's your `FROM`??? `SELECT WHERE NOT EXIST()`.  `SELECT` from where?

Comment: @Eric That query works in the development mysql server

Comment: There is nothing in this statement that should cause backward compatibility issues. So maybe your python script is not building it properly.

Comment: @P.Salmon The script works well in the local server too

Comment: Yeah got that. You need to check python..(BTW its not a good idea to promote stuff to a production environment that is different to dev/testing/staging or risk this kind of thing biting you).

Comment: I edited your tags and question. You are not using MySQL, you're using MariaDB. MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010, and it has gradually become less and less compatible. You should not think of MariaDB as MySQL-compatible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

`FROM DUAL` is required in some mysql-server version, so to get it working the query needs to be changed to:

```
INSERT
INTO
    devices(
        source_id,
        serialnumber,
        NAME,
        location_desc
    )
SELECT
    2,
    '5996B',
    'Barbate',
    'CADIZ'
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        devices
    WHERE
        serialnumber = '5996B'
)
```

I hope somebody find this useful